# vb.net bubble chart with gradient style in each buble to make it look like a ball

Tags: vb.net, 3d, bubble-chart

I have a bubble chart in vb.net with the code below and I would like to make the bubbles appear with a gradient stlyle to look like a ball (rather than a circle)

```
Dim xValues As Double() = {10.62, 75.54, 60.45}
Dim yValues As Double() = {650.62, 50.54, 600.45}
Dim size As Integer() = {10, 20, 30}
Dim names As String() = {"a", "b", "c"}


Chart5.Series("Series1").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble
Chart5.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues, size, names)
Chart5.Series("Series1").MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle
For i = 0 To 2
        Chart5.Series("Series1").Points(i).Label = names(i)
Next
```

I tried:

```
    Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").BackSecondaryColor = Drawing.Color.Green
    Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").MarkerColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
    Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.Center
```

... and

```
    For i = Region_From To Region_To
        Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").Points(i).Label = names(i)
        Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").Points(i).BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.Center
        Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").Points(i).Color = Drawing.Color.Aqua
        Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").Points(i).BackSecondaryColor = Drawing.Color.Green
    Next
```

... but with no success

Any ideas on how to achive this 3d/ball effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your 1st option to

```
Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").BackSecondaryColor = Drawing.Color.Green
Chart_Analysis.Series("Series1").MarkerColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
Chart_Analysis.ChartAreas("Series1").BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.Center
```

Note the change to ChartAreas on the third line.  I have found that sometimes you think you should be coding against the series, but you should be using ChartAreas.

Comment: Thanks APrough for your quick reply. Unfortunatelly I'm just getting dark blue circles. The ChartAreas don't seem to make any difference